# resolving overloads in boost.python

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python

I have a C++ class like this:

```
class ConnectionBase
{
public:
    ConnectionBase();
    template <class T> Publish(const T&);

private:
    virtual void OnEvent(const Overload_a&) {}
    virtual void OnEvent(const Overload_b&) {}
};
```

My templates & overloads are a known fixed set of types at compile time. The application code derives from ConnectionBase and overrides OnEvent for the events it cares about. I can do this because the set of types is known. OnEvent is private because the user never calls it, the class creates a thread that calls it as a callback. The C++ code works.

I have wrapped this in boost.python, I can import it and publish from python. I want to create the equivalent of the following in python :

```
class ConnectionDerived
{
public:
    ConnectionDerived();

private:
    virtual void OnEvent(const Overload_b&)
    { 
        // application code
    }
};
```

I don't care to (do not want to) expose the default OnEvent functions, since they're never called from application code - I only want to provide a body for the C++ class to call.
But ... since python isn't typed, and all the boost.python examples I've seen dealing with internals are on the C++ side, I'm a little puzzled as to how to do this. How do I override specific overloads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating C++ virtual functions that can be overridden in Python requires some work - see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html#python.class_virtual_functions). You will need to create a wrapper function in a derived class that calls the Python method. Here is how it can work:

```
struct ConnectionBaseWrap : ConnectionBase, wrapper<ConnectionBase>
{
    void OnEvent(const Overload_a &obj) {
        if (override f = get_override("OnEventOverloadA"))
            f(obj);
    }
    void OnEvent(const Overload_b &obj) {
        if (override f = get_override("OnEventOverloadB"))
            f(obj);
    }
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(yourmodule) {
    class_<ConnectionBaseWrap, boost::noncopyable>("ConnectionBase")
        //Your additional definitions here.
    ;
}
```

Some notes:

- Since you won't be calling the base class's OnEvent function from Python, you don't need to define it with `.def`. If you did want to define it, you'd need to give the two overloaded versions different names, like [here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/functions.html#python.overloading)
- The two overloads will call different Python methods: `OnEventOverloadA` and `OnEventOverloadB`. Another option is to have them both call the same method `OnEvent`, and then one Python method will override both overloads.